# Android make AsyncTask wait for the activity to resume inside a for loop

Tags: android, loops, android-asynctask

I have a for loop inside `onActivityResult()` method that creates a `Runnable` object and assign in to an `AsyncTask`. Each `Runnable` object is responsible of operating on a pdf file, sealing it with a password and then starting an `startActivityForResult()` method with an `Intent` to send an email.

Everything works as a charm except that my problem is that the for loop will start all the `AsyncTask` immediately even though the the activity is paused and the user is on the email client app. I want to make sure that the next `AsyncTask` doesn't execute until the user gets back to the application after pressing send email button on the email client app.

**UPDATE**

```
 if (requestCode == 2) {
        // Create Insurer annexe, seal document with insurer password and trigger sending email
        int lastInsurerPosition = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().size(); i++) {
            if (Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(i).getCar().getInsurerPosition() != -1 &&
                    !insurersEmails[Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(i).getCar().getInsurerPosition()].equals("null") &&
                    Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(i).getSendOption() != 1 &&
                    Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(i).getSendOption() != 2) {
                lastInsurerPosition = i;
            }
        }
        if (lastInsurerPosition != -1) {
            final int lastInsurerPositionCopy = lastInsurerPosition;

            for (int i = 0; i < Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().size(); i++) {
                String insurerEmail = "null";
                if (Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(i).getCar().getInsurerPosition() != -1) {
                    insurerEmail = insurersEmails[Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(i).getCar().getInsurerPosition()];
                }
                if (Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(i).getSendOption() != 1 &&
                        Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(i).getSendOption() != 2 &&
                        !insurerEmail.equals("null")) {
                    final int finalI = i;
                    Runnable progressRunnable = new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                String[] toArray = new String[1];
                                toArray[0] = insurersEmails[Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(finalI).getCar().getInsurerPosition()];
                                String subject = getResources().getString(R.string.pdf_joint_report);

                                InputStream is;
                                String str;
                                byte[] buffer = null;
                                int size;

                                if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("en")) {
                                    is = getAssets().open("insurerEmailTemplateENG.html");
                                } else {
                                    is = getAssets().open("insurerEmailTemplateFR.html");
                                }
                                size = is.available();

                                buffer = new byte[size];
                                is.read(buffer);
                                is.close();

                                String destPath = Constat.getInstance().getPdfPath().replace(".pdf", "_copy" + Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(finalI).getNumAccident() + ".pdf");
                                String destPath1 = Constat.getInstance().getPdfPath().replace(".pdf", "_copy1.pdf");

                                if (insurersPdfStructure[Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(finalI).getCar().getInsurerPosition()].equals("1")) {
                                    List<File> filesList = new ArrayList<>();
                                    if (PdfController.getInstance(activityRef.get()).getAnnexePref()) {
                                        filesList.add(new File(Constat.getInstance().getPdfPath()));
                                        filesList.add(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + PACKAGE_NAME + "/annexe.pdf"));
                                    } else {
                                        filesList.add(new File(Constat.getInstance().getPdfPath()));
                                    }
                                    File outputFile = new File(destPath1);
                                    try {
                                        Utilities.mergePdfDocuments(filesList, outputFile);
                                    } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    try {
                                        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                                        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(destPath1));

                                        document.open();
                                        PdfContentByte cb = writer.getDirectContent();

                                        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(Constat.getInstance().getPdfPath()));
                                        for (int j = 0; j < reader.getNumberOfPages(); j++) {
                                            PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, j + 1);
                                            if (j == 0) {
                                                PdfDictionary parameters = new PdfDictionary();
                                                parameters.put(PdfName.MODDATE, new PdfDate());

                                                PdfFileSpecification fileSpec = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(
                                                        writer, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + PACKAGE_NAME + "/annexe.xml",
                                                        "annexe.xml", null, "application/xml", parameters, 0);
                                                fileSpec.put(new PdfName("annexe"), new PdfName("Data"));
                                                writer.addFileAttachment("annexe.xml", fileSpec);

                                                PdfFileSpecification fileSpec1 = PdfFileSpecification.fileEmbedded(
                                                        writer, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + PACKAGE_NAME + "/xml_def.xsd",
                                                        "xml_def.xsd", null, "application/xml", parameters, 0);
                                                fileSpec.put(new PdfName("xml_def"), new PdfName("Data"));
                                                writer.addFileAttachment("xml_def.xsd", fileSpec1);

                                                PdfArray array = new PdfArray();
                                                array.add(fileSpec.getReference());
                                                array.add(fileSpec1.getReference());
                                                writer.getExtraCatalog().put(new PdfName("AF"), array);
                                            }
                                            cb.addTemplate(page, 0, 0);
                                            document.newPage();
                                        }

                                        document.close();

                                    } catch (DocumentException | IOException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }

                                try {
                                    File file1 = new File(destPath);
                                    file1.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                                    Utilities.sealPdf(destPath1, destPath, insurersPasswords[Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(finalI).getCar().getInsurerPosition()]);
                                } catch (DocumentException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
                                    uris.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(destPath)));
                                else
                                    uris.add(FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(destPath)));

                                str = new String(buffer);
                                str = str.replace("{#CAROWNER}", Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(finalI).getCar().getOwner().getFirstName() + " " + Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(finalI).getCar().getOwner().getLastName());

                                final int i1 = finalI;
                                final int lastInsurerPosition1 = lastInsurerPositionCopy;
                                final String[] toArray1 = toArray;
                                final String str1 = str;
                                final String subject1 = subject;
                                final ArrayList<Uri> uris1 = uris;

                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        if (i1 != lastInsurerPosition1) {
                                            Utilities.sendEmails(activityRef.get(), toArray1, null, str1, subject1, uris1, 3);
                                        } else {
                                            Utilities.sendEmails(activityRef.get(), toArray1, null, str1, subject1, uris1, 4);
                                        }
                                        while (!activityRef.get().hasWindowFocus()) {
                                            try {
                                                Thread.sleep(2000);
                                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                });

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    LongOperation lo = new LongOperation(PdfActivity.this, progressRunnable, getResources().getString(R.string.generating),
                            getResources().getString(R.string.generating_email_n_for_insurer, Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(i).getDriver().getFirstName()));
                    lo.execute();
                }
            }
        } else {
            // delete signature image file and redirect user to home screen
            for (int j = 0; j < Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().size(); j++) {
                File file = new File(Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(j).getSignatureFilePath());
                file.delete();
            }

            // Reset Pdf instance
            PdfController.destroyInstance();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.send_success))
                    .setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.emails_sended))
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.ok_button), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May you please show some code of yours for better understanding of the question.?

Comment: @Danger please consult my post update.

Comment: One thing, you should never have more than 5 AsynTasks running at a time in android.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable hint. In my case the max number of AsyncTasks is 3. What i want to achieve is to make the for loop inside the activity result wait until the activity is resumed so the next AsyncTask can be executed and the for loop continues to perform.

Comment: One thing I want to understand, once Activity's onActivityResult() method is called, this means controll is back to that Activity, Your activity is resumed, it's no longer in paused state.

Comment: that's true, but i need to call the startActivityForResult method to execute the intent that sends the email.

Comment: you may use some data structure, a Queue maybe, where you push all PDF files to be processed, start only the first one, when the asyncTask complete start the sealer runnable, that will open email send app, the trick is here, `onResume()` or `onActivityResult()` of activity, check if the queue is not empty, and pop next item, and start the asyncTask again ...

Comment: @Yazan i don't think i got your point, can you post a snippet please.

Comment: i can write an abstract snippet, cuz i don't understand your code, it can be a guide (if it helps) to alter your code to, i will post answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can write an abstract snippet, cuz i don't understand your code, it can be a guide (if it helps) to alter your code to, i will post answer

Declare this class scope

```
Queue<MyItem> queue = new LinkedList<MyItem>();
//MyItem is a type i think it's what in 'Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList()'
//it should be the type you have to be processed (email and PDF)
```

your current code (onActivityResult) don't start processing, just add to Queue, and process first item in Queue:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    for(int i = 0; i < Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().size(); i++){
        //add to-be-processed items in the Queue
        queue.add(Constat.getInstance().getAccidentList().get(i));
    }//for loop

    //when loop finish, start processing first item
    MyItem item = queue.remove();
    processItem(item);
}
```

each time onResume() is called, check queue size, if empty 
that can be all items were processed, or this is the first time the activity is open, so no items to process yet

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if(queue.size() != 0){
        processItem(queue.remove());
    }//we still have items to process
}
```

your actual code is here, to create PDF, create email , send email.

```
private void processItem(MyItem item){
    //start runnable ... to create PDF ...

    //create email body, and start email sending action
}
```

Comment: I adopted your solution with a little tweek.
Inside the for loop I constructed a Runnable object for every Accident on the list. then added it to the Queue.
In the onResume() method i check if the queue is not empty and then proceed with asynctask which will execute the runnable.
Thank you for your valuable answer.